# jQuery code does not work in Safari for Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have written the code below in my javascript file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#fbhtmlImage .image_thumb").live('click',function(){ $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
    $("#dropboxImageContent .image_thumb").live('click',function(){ $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
    $("#instagramFrm .image_thumb").live('click',function(){ $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
});
```

It is working fine in all browsers including Safari for Mac. But the same code is not working in Safari for Windows.

I have also tried,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(document).on("click","#fbhtmlImage .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
    $(document).on("click","#DropboxContent .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
    $(document).on("click","#instagramFrm .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
});
```

Comment: By the way, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and was removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: I can help you @ashish if you provide hTmL code

Comment: I'm not sure whether that *update* was supposed to be a fix (if so, post it in an answer) or another thing that didn't work. I also don't know what "is not working" means: what is supposed to happen. I also don't think this question is answerable without HTML. Voting to close as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @TRiG I have clearly mentioned what is not working. The functionality of triggering a label click event is not working. Please read the full question carefully. And in the question the update was the fix according to rohit. But it didnot work as well. So I have posted my fix in the answer which helped me to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this by below code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var os = navigator.platform;
    os = os.toLowerCase();

    if(os.indexOf('win') >= 0 && jQuery.browser.safari){
        //For Windows Safari
        $(document).on("click","#fbhtmlImage .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("input").click(); });
        $(document).on("click","#DropboxContent .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("input").click(); });
        $(document).on("click","#instagramFrm .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("input").click(); });
    }
    else{
        $(document).on("click","#fbhtmlImage .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
        $(document).on("click","#DropboxContent .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
        $(document).on("click","#instagramFrm .image_thumb",function() { $(this).parent().find("label").click(); });
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

for e.g.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#fbhtmlImage .image_thumb").on('click',function(){ 
        $(this).parent().find("label").click(); }); //For Facebook
    });
```

hope it will work as `.live()` is deprecated.

For ref : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: You can provide example of using `.on()` and/or reference to `.on()` docs for answer's completeness.

Comment: sorry @rohit your answer did not help me... it is still not working in safari for windows.
I have also updated code and giving you my updated code in the revised question